# UIImagePickerController on iPad is blank

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to display a `UIImagePickerController` on iPad but it won't display my photos. I have the following code:

```
let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
imagePicker.delegate = imagePickerDelegate
imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
imagePicker.allowsEditing = false

if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
    imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    imagePicker.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = cell      
    imagePicker.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = cell.bounds
    imagePicker.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = .any
}

let photoAuthorizationStatus = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()
switch photoAuthorizationStatus {
case .authorized:
    self.present(imagePicker, animated: true)
case .notDetermined:
    PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { [weak self] newStatus in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if newStatus == .authorized {
                self?.present(imagePicker, animated: true)
            } else {
                print("User denied")
            }
        }
    }
case .denied,
    .restricted:
    break
@unknown default:
    break
}
```

What happens is it asks for permissions, and then the popover presentation controller pops up, briefly shows my photos and then switches to showing nothing (a blank white screen inside the popover presentation controller). Why is this?

Comment: Unrelated to your issue but there is no need to check for iPad. It's fine to setup the image picker as a popover on an iPhone.

Comment: @rmaddy ah didn't know that, thank you!

Comment: Same behaviour when user already .authorized before?

Comment: @KaiHuppmann Yep